# How to deal with web.config in a url search term

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, url-routing

I am creating a search page in ASP.NET MVC3.

The url of calling the action was:

```
http://mydomain/Search?q=searchterm
```

it works fine if i search the keyword "web.config":

```
http://mydomain/Search?q=web.config
```

But now, i want the url to be:

```
http://mydomain/Search/searchterm
```

I have done this with adding the route into global.asax, but when i search "web.config", like `http://mydomain/Search/web.config` the server will end my request, because it thinks i am requesting the physical web.config file in the search directory.

Is there anyway to let asp.net consider the {q} in the url "search/{q}" as the parameter of the search action, not a request of a file?

Comment: See this article http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `RegisterRoutes` in `Global.asax` you could enable requests for existing files to pass through the routing engine:

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

Notice that if you do that all request will now go through the ASP.NET MVC routing engine. So if you don't want to see broken images or javascript and CSS references you will need to explicitly exclude them:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("scripts/{resource}.js");
routes.IgnoreRoute("content/{resource}.css");
routes.IgnoreRoute("iamges/{resource}.png");
routes.IgnoreRoute("iamges/{resource}.jpeg");
...
```

Also if you are hosting your application in IIS 7+ you need to remove some of the security filters that prevent you from serving `web.config` an `.config` files in general:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions>
          <remove fileExtension=".config"/>
        </fileExtensions>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="web.config"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: this seems to be a good idea, but after i add this rule in global.asax, all my images are not shown :(

Comment: Make sure you have excluded static resources from routing: `routes.IgnoreRoute("images/{image}.png");`. Do the same for other static resources that you need to handle and adjust the url for your site.

Comment: wow, it works after i add your code to system.webServer/security. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the URL Rewriter Module in IIS to do this for you; it would remove the necessary logic from `Global.asax` and allow you to use it across your website for simplifying the urls.

[Rewriter Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/)

[Adding a Rewriter Rule](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/)

Sample rule:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite to search">
      <match url="^search/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="search.aspx?q={R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```